# Weird SPAN element rendering in Safari (on iPhone)

Tags: iphone, html, mobile, safari

Whenever there is a SPAN element in HTML content, the mobile version of Safari renders content differently- it seems that font size increases for the whole paragraph. Consider two examples.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid red; width:500px;">
<p>This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

and

```
<div style="border: 1px solid red; width:500px;">
<p>This is a <span>paragraph</span>. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Second example breaks page structure because font size increases, and thus the content exceeds div's width. Is there any way around this (besides not using SPAN)?

iPhone OS 3.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display of those two HTML fragments look identical to me on iPhone Safari (also iPhone OS 3.1.2).

Is there any CSS being applied to SPAN tags?

[Edit: I see the difference now; you won't see any difference if both examples are on the same page.]

[Added:]
By explicitly setting the size, it appears you can get consistent text size between the two. For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
  div, p, span {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: No, there is no CSS at all. Look at these two links:
http://www.eparks.lv/stackoverflow/span.html
http://www.eparks.lv/stackoverflow/nospan.html

Comment: I definitely see his problem. With the span, the font of the whole paragraph looks larger.

Comment: OK, those two links do display differently. I had created a page which contained both examples, and they looked identical.

Comment: Setting span size does solve the problem but I think that it is a bug in rendering..

Answer (score 5):

try adding `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;` to the CSS and iPhone safari should stop making the span font size look differnet.

Comment: This is the correct answer to fix. I've applied it into `body` and works awesomely.

Answer (score 0):

Paul, could you try explicitly setting the font-size for the span to match that of the paragraph tag and see if this solves your issue?

Comment: Please, try these two links:
http://www.eparks.lv/stackoverflow/span.html
http://www.eparks.lv/stackoverflow/nospan.html